# Linux File System Cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache

I was wondering if there was a way to tell how many more "writes" are left on a file system device in linux?  An example: when you move a lot of data to a flash drive, it may not write all data immediately.  In this case, I would like to see (preferably) how much more is left to write, or even if it's a flag (such as 0 = writes complete or 1 = writes remain).  Is there a particular command or file that holds that information?

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful the following utilities:
`lsof`
`dstat`.
Finally, you can force pending writes to be flush to the HDD subsystem with `sync` CLI command.

Comment: I knew about the sync `sync` command, which is helpful but I want to be able to see when something needs to be "synced".  Both `lsof` and `dstat` are helpful, but seem to be a little too broad (not specific enough) for what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how many kilobytes *globally* are waiting to be written, contained in "dirty" pages, however I don't know how to do this for individual devices.

```
grep Dirty /proc/meminfo
```

There are tunables in /proc/sys/vm and /sys/block/${dev_name} which can affect how rapidly dirty pages are written out; usually, they are modified by software like laptop-mode-tools.